# how to add event to calendar in j2me/ LWUIT

Tags: java-me, calendar, lwuit

Is it possible to programatically add an event to a Calendar on Button click in j2me for S60 using LWUIT? I guess there has to be an Native Extension for this, right? Or is there any other way.

Please Help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the phone's Calendar you can do this with PIM API. Please check addEventInfo method and how it is used at http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/pim/pim5/